# Best practice for MATLAB for loop index

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, indexing

I was surprised to find the following difference cost between running the MATLAB for loops:

```
ksize = 100;
klist = 1:ksize;

tic
for m = 1:100000        
    for k = 1:ksize

    end        
end
toc

tic
for m = 1:100000        
    for k = klist

    end        
end
toc
```

The only difference being the way the index list is created.  I would have suspected the second version to be faster, but lo!

```
Elapsed time is 0.055400 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.695904 seconds.
```

My question is twofold: what is responsible for the above result, and where else does this nuance (or similar ones) occur in MATLAB programming? I hope to be able to better spot these inefficiencies in the future.  Thanks all.

Comment: This is probably due to JIT acceleration, because if you turn it off using `feature accel off`, you get similar results for both runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation in [`for()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/for.html) states:

> ```
> for index = values
>    ...
> end
> ```
>
> where `values` has one of the following forms:
>
> - ...
> - `valArray`: creates a column vector index from subsequent columns of array `valArray` on each iteration. For example, on the first iteration, `index = valArray(:,1)`. The loop executes for a maximum of `n` times, where `n` is the number of columns of valArray, given by `numel(valArray, 1, :)`. The input `valArray` can be of any MATLAB data type, including a string, cell array, or struct.

Therefore, I assume there is a significant **overhead** and the compiler does not check whether `1:ksize == klist` to exploit the faster implementation. In other words, per Eitan's comment, the JIT applies to the first two types of accepted *values*.

The whole problem is related to the following indexing task (column vs element):

```
tic
for m = 1:100000        
    for k = 1:ksize
        klist(:,k);
    end        
end
toc

tic
for m = 1:100000        
    for k = 1:ksize
        klist(k);
    end        
end
toc

Index column:  ~2.9 sec
Index element: ~0.28 sec
```

You can see how `klist(:,k)` effectively slows down the faster loop indicating that the issue in `for k = klist` is related to the column indexing used in this case.

For additional details see this [lengthy discussion on (inefficient) indexing](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/54522-why-is-indexing-vectors-matrices-in-matlab-very-inefficient).

Answer (score 2):

My answer is speculation (because only Mathworks guys know the implementation of their product), but I think the first `k` loop is optimized to not create the actual array of indices, but to just scan them one by one, because it explicitely shows how the values are "built". The second `k` loop cannot be optimized, because the interpreter doesn't know beforehand if the content of the index array will grow uniformly. So, each time the loop starts, it will <s>copy</s> access the original `klist` and that's why you have the performance penalty.

**Later edit:** Another performance penalty might be from indexed access int the `klist` array, compared to creating the index values "on the fly."

Comment: I wonder if you could test this by creating a class that derives from `double` and overrides `copy`...

Comment: @wakjah Checked, and it's not about copying (there's no copying taking place actually -- I think copy-on-write still works). It's about subscripted reference in `klist`. I corrected mt post. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @wakjah On another hand, `copy` works on handle subclasses, and one cannot inherit value *and* handle classes the same time (at lear not in R2010a that I have). I wonder if I actually overridden anything... :D

Comment: This is true... perhaps in the constructor/`subsasgn` of a value class then?